# Percentile and Standard deviation

Tags: statistics

In a survey of women in a certain country (ages 20-29), the mean height was 66.5 inches with a standard deviation of 2.82 inches.

A) What height represents the 85th percentile?

B) What height represents the first quartile?

Comment: What have you tried? This will help people provide an answer that's suitable to your level of understanding.

Comment: i havent really tired anything because i dont know where to start. ive looked up similar questions and i still dont know what to do

Comment: You'd need to know how the heights are distributed but it's a fair guess that you are supposed to assume they are Normally distributed.  Have you been working on that topic?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make assumptions about your population to make this work, e.g. probably they want you to assume height is normal/Gaussian distributed. In that case, you want to know how many standard deviations above the mean represents a particular percentile. An online calculator of look up table of z-score will give you this. (You can read about z-score for normal distribution online if it's unfamiliar to you.)